# Foreman does not kill processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreman

For start application i use Foreman.
Foreman start process from Procfile

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec rake environment resque:work QUEUE=send_mail
api: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT
```

If i press control+C in console where i run foreman, foreman is ended but ran process is not killed. Is it possible to kill process that foreman ran when foreman killed.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Foreman won't kill [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) servers written in Ruby.

Comment: +1 here... I have problems with Foreman killing Ruby Faye servers as well. I suspect it has to do with the signal Foreman sends to processes it's started in order to kill them, although when I start a Faye server manually I have no issues killing it with ctrl+c.

Comment: Does it kill them eventually?  As I understand Foreman, it'll issue a SIGTERM, then 10 seconds later a SIGKILL.

Answer (score 10):

Example below assumes port used is 4567, then do:

```
lsof -i :4567
```

This gives you the pid of the process, say 34564, then kill it with

```
kill -9 34564
```

If you are on windows, install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to get `lsof` and `kill` commands.

Comment: And if you don't want to search for the PID then you can use `killall "foreman: master"`

Answer (score 1):

Thin doesn't terminate as long as there are open connections.
Faye uses long-polling or WebSockets (long lasting connections).
So the end result is that Thin is waiting for your Faye connections to close.

Try to turn of the signal handlers installed by Thin and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've assembled a little one-liner which finds the process ids and kills the processes

```
kill -9 `lsof -P -i :5000 | sed -n 's/python *\([0-9]*\).*\:5000.*/\1/p'`
```

In this case, I'm running python processes on port 5000, but you may be running some other type of processes on other ports, so you'll need to customize this one-liner accordingly.